# msm_otg kernel wakelock preventing deep sleep

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, battery-life, wakelock

Ever since upgrading my stock Sprint Galaxy S3 to the official Jelly Bean release, my phone won't go in deep sleep at all, it's constantly at 384MHz.  It's because of msm_otg kernel wakelock.  Anyone have any idea how to disable that?

```
===================
General Information
===================
BetterBatteryStats version: 1.11.0.0
Creation Date: 2012-10-29 14:02:58
Statistic Type: (3) Since Unplugged
Since 2 h 10 m 50 s 
VERSION.RELEASE: 4.1.1
BRAND: samsung
DEVICE: d2spr
MANUFACTURER: samsung
MODEL: SPH-L710
OS.VERSION: 3.0.31-329968
BOOTLOADER: L710VPBLJ7
HARDWARE: qcom
FINGERPRINT: samsung/d2spr/d2spr:4.1.1/JRO03L/L710VPBLJ7:user/release-keys
ID: JRO03L
TAGS: release-keys
USER: se.infra
PRODUCT: d2spr
RADIO: L710VPBLJ7
Rooted: false
============
Battery Info
============
Level lost [%]: 19 Bat.: 19% (74% to 55%) [8.7%/h]
Voltage lost [mV]: 259 (4036-3777)
===========
Other Usage
===========
Awake (): 2 h 10 m 49 s  (7849 s) Ratio: 100.0%
Wifi On (): 2 h 10 m 50 s  (7850 s) Ratio: 100.0%
Wifi Running (): 2 h 10 m 50 s  (7850 s) Ratio: 100.0%
Bluetooth On (): 2 h 10 m 50 s  (7850 s) Ratio: 100.0%
No Data Connection (): 1 h 28 m 40 s  (5320 s) Ratio: 67.8%
No or Unknown Signal (): 1 h 28 m 40 s  (5320 s) Ratio: 67.8%
Screen On (): 16 m 13 s  (973 s) Ratio: 12.4%
Deep Sleep ():  (0 s) Ratio: 0.0%
=========
Wakelocks
=========
NetworkLocationLocator (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 6 m 15 s  (375 s) Count:339 4.8%
SignalCollector.ScannerThread (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 3 m 19 s  (199 s) Count:63 2.5%
AlarmReceiver (com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.Clock): 39 s  (39 s) Count:14 0.5%
AlarmManager (in.vineetsirohi.customwidget.Ultimate custom widget (UCCW)): 34 s  (34 s) Count:28 0.4%
AlarmManager (Android System): 29 s  (29 s) Count:278 0.4%
LocationReceiverService (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 17 s  (17 s) Count:857 0.2%
EntriesRefresh_wakelock (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.Google Search): 17 s  (17 s) Count:16 0.2%
*sync*_gmail-ls (com.google.android.gm.Gmail): 16 s  (16 s) Count:12 0.2%
CheckinsNotificationService (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 12 s  (12 s) Count:685 0.2%
ActivityManager-Launch (Android System): 12 s  (12 s) Count:51 0.2%
AlarmManager (com.espn.score_center.ScoreCenter): 9 s  (9 s) Count:135 0.1%
AlarmManager (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 8 s  (8 s) Count:1701 0.1%
*sync*_com.google.android.apps.plus.content.EsProvider (com.google.android.apps.plus.Google+): 7 s  (7 s) Count:1 0.1%
GmailProviderProviderChangedBroadcastWakeLock (com.google.android.gm.Gmail): 7 s  (7 s) Count:4 0.1%
*sync*_com.android.calendar (Calendar): 7 s  (7 s) Count:11 0.1%
FaceDetectionService (Android System): 6 s  (6 s) Count:144 0.1%
GTALK_ASYNC_CONN_com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.AndroidEndpoint (Google Services): 6 s  (6 s) Count:43 0.0%
AsyncCollectorListener (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 6 s  (6 s) Count:1089 0.1%
sleep_broadcast (Android System): 5 s  (5 s) Count:85 0.1%
*sync*_com.google.android.apps.docs (com.google.android.apps.docs.Drive): 5 s  (5 s) Count:6 0.0%
ConnectivityService (Android System): 5 s  (5 s) Count:146 0.0%
DocsSyncAdapter (com.google.android.apps.docs.Drive): 5 s  (5 s) Count:2 0.0%
PhoneWindowManager.mBroadcastWakeLock (Android System): 4 s  (4 s) Count:60 0.1%
NetworkLocationCallbackRunner (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 4 s  (4 s) Count:546 0.1%
NetworkLocationPassiveCollector (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 4 s  (4 s) Count:551 0.1%
LocationReportingService (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 4 s  (4 s) Count:1704 0.1%
NLP PendingIntent client in com.google.android.apps.maps (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 4 s  (4 s) Count:1224 0.1%
AlarmManager (com.levelup.beautifulwidgets.Beautiful Widgets): 4 s  (4 s) Count:131 0.1%
*sync*_com.android.contacts (Google Services): 3 s  (3 s) Count:4 0.0%
BackgroundRequestService (com.facebook.katana.Facebook): 3 s  (3 s) Count:29 0.0%
NLP PendingIntent client in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 3 s  (3 s) Count:166 0.0%
*sync*_com.sec.android.gallery3d.picasa.contentprovider (com.sec.android.gallery3d.Gallery): 2 s  (2 s) Count:2 0.0%
net.comcast.ottclient.common.sync.WakefulIntentService (net.comcast.ottclient.XFINITY Connect): 2 s  (2 s) Count:6 0.0%
RILJ (Phone): 2 s  (2 s) Count:70 0.0%
AlarmManager (com.android.providers.calendar.Calendar storage): 2 s  (2 s) Count:26 0.0%
AlarmManager (flipboard.app.Flipboard): 2 s  (2 s) Count:3 0.0%
*sync*_com.google.android.music.MusicContent (com.google.android.music.Google Play Music): 2 s  (2 s) Count:6 0.0%
NetworkStats (Android System): 2 s  (2 s) Count:43 0.0%
ScheduleNextAlarmWakeLock (com.android.providers.calendar.Calendar storage): 2 s  (2 s) Count:30 0.0%
*sync*_com.android.browser (Google Services): 1 s  (1 s) Count:80 0.0%
SyncLoopWakeLock (Android System): 1 s  (1 s) Count:377 0.0%
show keyguard (Android System): 1 s  (1 s) Count:9 0.0%
AudioOut_15 (1013): 1 s  (1 s) Count:5 0.0%
MQTT (com.facebook.katana.Facebook): 1 s  (1 s) Count:25 0.0%
GTALK_CONN (Google Services): 1 s  (1 s) Count:181 0.0%
*sync*_subscribedfeeds (Google Services): 1 s  (1 s) Count:109 0.0%
NfcAdapterManagerImpl (com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel.Wallet): 1 s  (1 s) Count:10 0.0%
AlarmManager (com.birdstep.android.cm.Sprint Connections Optimizer): 1 s  (1 s) Count:3 0.0%
Event Log Service (Google Services): 1 s  (1 s) Count:107 0.0%
AlarmManager (Google Services): 1 s  (1 s) Count:216 0.0%
NLP ActivityPendingIntent client in com.google.android.apps.maps (com.google.android.apps.maps.Maps): 1 s  (1 s) Count:205 0.0%
AudioOut_3 (1013): 1 s  (1 s) Count:6 0.0%
AudioOut_2 (1013): 1 s  (1 s) Count:7 0.0%
reset keyguard (Android System): 1 s  (1 s) Count:131 0.0%
AlarmManager (org.fueledinc.jackthreads.android.JackThreads): 1 s  (1 s) Count:24 0.0%
AlarmManager (com.facebook.katana.Facebook): 1 s  (1 s) Count:47 0.0%
================
Kernel Wakelocks
================
"msm_otg" (): 1 h 54 m 31 s  (6871 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1/0/0 87.1%
"wlan_rx_wake" (): 25 m 11 s  (1511 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1393/0/1393 19.2%
"PowerManagerService" (): 13 m 25 s  (805 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1128/0/0 10.2%
"wlan_ctrl_wake" (): 8 m 17 s  (497 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)236/0/236 6.3%
"bam_dmux_wakelock" (): 4 m 4 s  (244 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)336/0/168 1.8%
"sec-battery-monitor" (): 1 m 45 s  (105 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)233/0/0 1.3%
"smdcntl0" (): 1 m 32 s  (92 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1795/0/85 1.2%
"wlan_wake" (): 1 m 18 s  (78 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)35988/1/0 1.0%
"BTLowPower" (): 39 s  (39 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)16/0/16 0.5%
"msm_serial_hs_dma" (): 30 s  (30 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)16/0/0 0.4%
"radio-interface" (): 19 s  (19 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)40/0/0 0.2%
"alarm" (): 12 s  (12 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1076/0/0 0.2%
"smdcntl1" (): 11 s  (11 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)12/0/6 0.2%
"msm_serial_hs_rx" (): 10 s  (10 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)37/0/37 0.1%
"vib_present" (): 7 s  (7 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)16/0/0 0.1%
"rmt_storage_1093353344" (): 3 s  (3 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)10/0/0 0.0%
"rmt_storage_1093353168" (): 3 s  (3 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)10/0/0 0.0%
"power-supply" (): 1 s  (1 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)233/0/0 0.0%
"sec-battery-measure" (): 1 s  (1 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)262/0/0 0.0%
"alarm_rtc" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)15/0/1 0.0%
"pm8xxx_adc_wakelock" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)262/0/0 0.0%
"mmc1_detect" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)2/0/2 0.0%
"mmc0_detect" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)2/0/2 0.0%
"qcril" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)865/0/0 0.0%
"KeyEvents" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)4189/0/0 0.0%
"ApmCommand" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)58/0/0 0.0%
"qmuxd_port_wl_0" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1742/0/0 0.0%
"event7-734" (system, com.sec.android.app.gamehub, com.android.providers.security, com.google.android.backup, com.android.providers.settings):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)35/0/0 0.0%
"event0-734" (system, com.android.server.vpn.enterprise):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1/0/0 0.0%
"event4-734" (system, com.android.server.vpn.enterprise):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1/0/0 0.0%
"event1-734" (system, com.android.server.vpn.enterprise):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1/0/0 0.0%
"event13-734" (system, com.microsoft.onx.app):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)57/0/0 0.0%
"event5-734" (system, com.asksven.betterbatterystats):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)11/0/0 0.0%
"event11-734" (system, com.android.server.vpn.enterprise):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1/0/0 0.0%
"event10-734" (system, com.android.server.vpn.enterprise):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1/0/0 0.0%
"event9-734" (system, com.android.server.vpn.enterprise):  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)1/0/0 0.0%
"qmuxd_port_wl_1" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)6/0/0 0.0%
"msm_ipc_read" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)20/0/0 0.0%
"msm_ipc_router_smd_xprt" ():  (0 s) Cnt:(c/wc/ec)41/0/0 0.0%
======================
Alarms (requires root)
======================
======================
Network (requires root)
======================
==========
CPU States
==========
384 MHz (): 1 h 43 m 3 s  78.4%
486 MHz (): 3 m 46 s  2.9%
594 MHz (): 1 m 53 s  1.4%
702 MHz (): 2 m 8 s  1.6%
810 MHz (): 2 m 40 s  2.0%
918 MHz (): 3 m 59 s  3.0%
1.03 GHz (): 2 m 3 s  1.6%
1.13 GHz (): 1 m 39 s  1.3%
1.24 GHz (): 1 m 20 s  1.0%
1.35 GHz (): 31 s  0.4%
1.46 GHz (): 24 s  0.3%
1.51 GHz (): 7 m 53 s  6.0%
Deep Sleep ():  0.0%
==================
Reference overview
==================
Custom: Reference custom_ref created 0 s (Wl: null; KWl: null; NetS: null; Alrm: null; Proc: null; Oth: null; CPU: null)
Since charged: Reference since_charged_ref created 0 s (Wl: null; KWl: null; NetS: null; Alrm: null; Proc: null; Oth: null; CPU: null)
Since screen off: Reference since_screen_off created 0 s (Wl: null; KWl: null; NetS: null; Alrm: null; Proc: null; Oth: null; CPU: null)
Since unplugged: Reference since_unplugged_ref created 1 h 35 m 58 s  (Wl: 43 elements; KWl: 27elements; NetS: null; Alrm: null; Proc: 12 elements; Oth: 7 elements; CPU: 13 elements)
Since boot: Reference since_boot created 59 s  (Wl: 11 elements; KWl: 0elements; NetS: null; Alrm: null; Proc: 1 elements; Oth: 6 elements; CPU: 13 elements)
```

Comment: Whoa. Where do you get so much info from ?

Comment: @rjt.rockx this was a really long time ago, but it was from an app called BetterBatteryStats.  It still exists and is highly rated, but I don't know what it's capabilities are any more, and I don't know if something better exists now.

Answer (score 1):

I started having major battery drain after updating some apps recently. Betterbatterystats showed this same msm_otg as what was preventing sleep.

Uninstalling Google+ updates, and stopping Picasa sync fixed it. I didn't have a Picasa album showing in my gallery as the [link](http://blog.gadgethelpline.com/remove-unwanted-picasa-albums-samsung-galaxy-siii/) indicates, but I am 100% that the G+ and Picasa connection was the culprit.

The steps listed in the link are:

- Open Settings, scroll down and tap Application Manager Tap All
- Select Google+ Tap Uninstall Updates
- Return to home screen by pressing middle button
- Find Google+ in apps menu and open it
- Follow setup steps, when prompted about Auto Uploads choose to turn
  them off
- Close Google+ Open Settings, scroll down and tap Accounts and Sync
- Select your Google account
- Untick these options if available: Sync Google+, Sync Google Photos,
  Sync Picasa Web Albums
- Tap Sync now at the bottom
- Tap Back arrow twice to return to main settings screen
- Open Application Manager Tap All Scroll down and tap Gallery
- Tap Clear Data
- Return to home screen by pressing middle button
- Open Gallery app, you should now find that the Picasa albums are
  gone!

Answer (score -1):

This otg bug comes when phone is plugged into a computer in mass transfer mode . not sure if happens if you improperly disconnect the device . but that is the problem .

You can reboot to make sure its not running in background and sucking up battery.

Answer (score -2):

In my case it was easy. 
I've tried everything. 
Service need to change the resistance behind the power socket on the motherboard.
And now I don't have to reboot all the time. The battery can go into deep sleep.